# What about [in-loco-parentis] and [biting] tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

When (re-)tagging questions, I sometimes have a hard time finding appropriate tags and wonder if the existing ones are sufficient. Hence I want to discuss two possible tags that might come in very handy. Also feel free to suggest better names for the tags, they are not set in stone.

---

[in-loco-parentis](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/in-loco-parentis)

There is currently no good tag for parenting situations in which the involved parties are neither related to each other (parents, mother, father, siblings, grandparents, family, extended-family) nor in some sort of legal relationship (adoption, step-parents, foster-parenting, blended-family). Special cases are teachers and babysitting.

Quite common are questions by people in a relationship, in which at least one of them has own children, but they are not married. In this case, [blended-family](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blended-family) doesn't really fit. It might also be about other people's children, e. g. your child's friends (in your house), or just some children outside you may not even know. We do allow these questions, but we can't really capture the relationship between adult and child with a tag.

I just give a few examples. There are more, but it's not easy to find them all through search easily.

- [A stranger's child throws a piece of garbage onto the ground, out of sight of their parents. Should I say or do anything?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/29621/30519)
- [How to support a 7-year-old who is behind in school for reasons other than intellectual and learning disability?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/34183/30519)
- [Uncontrollable child](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/31981/30519)
- [Discipline and how to properly address a 7yr old with behavior/stubbornness & crying for everything](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/29399/30519)
- [Topics for kids for moving in with girlfriend and kids](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/29405/30519)

Do you think it would make sense to have another tag for this special kind of parenting relationship?

---

[biting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biting)

If you search for questions containg the word "biting" you get [60 results](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/search?q=biting%20is%3Aquestion).

While we do have tags like [violence](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/violence), [abuse](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abuse), [bullying](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bullying), [aggression](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aggression), [anger](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anger) or even [hitting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hitting), we don't have one for biting.

Reading questions here on Parenting.SE, it becomes clear that *biting* is very important - it also makes sense, since it's a very easy way of inflicting damage.

Now, not all these questions are about *biting* as a way of being violent towards others, but also about biting food.

Do we need a tag about biting? And if so, should it cover every kind of biting, or just be about violence (or about biting food) etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think having a tag for biting makes loads of sense of we have 60 questions on it!

I'm not so sold on an in-loco-parentis tag though ...

Comment: Thanks for answering! Should *biting* be for all questions about it (e. g. "How to teach my child to bite their food" and "How to make my child stop biting their peers?")? Why no *in-loco-parentis* tag? We allow questions that are not about "classiscal" parenting relationships, yet cannot really tag them.

Comment: Sorry - yes, biting as an aggression, not as part of eating. Re in-loco-parentis... I just don't really have an opinion either way (sorry)